# ASA 5550 show perfmon "VALID CONNS RATE in TCP INTERCEPT" meaning

Tags: cisco-asa

So I'm looking at the "show perfmon" output from my ASA (5550, 9.0 software), and am confused by the "VALID CONNS RATE in TCP INTERCEPT" output:

```
primary-int# sh perfmon    

PERFMON STATS:                     Current      Average
Xlates                              111/s          0/s
Connections                         155/s          0/s
TCP Conns                           106/s          0/s
UDP Conns                            45/s          0/s
URL Access                           66/s          0/s
URL Server Req                       41/s          0/s
TCP Fixup                          3761/s          0/s
TCP Intercept Established Conns       0/s          0/s
TCP Intercept Attempts                0/s          0/s
TCP Embryonic Conns Timeout           3/s          0/s
HTTP Fixup                         3761/s          0/s
FTP Fixup                             9/s          0/s
AAA Authen                            0/s          0/s
AAA Author                            0/s          0/s
AAA Account                           0/s          0/s

VALID CONNS RATE in TCP INTERCEPT:    Current      Average
                                       N/A         5027.59%
```

I can't really figure out what this means, nor why it's such a ridiculously high number... though I suspect the latter is due to this being a failover ASA in an HA pair, which has been powered on and in standby state for several months. Of course, I didn't get a chance to look at these numbers on the primary. :(

So, 2 part question:
**What does "VALID CONNS RATE in TCP INTERCEPT" mean?** and 
**why is the average so extraordinarily high?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does "VALID CONNS RATE in TCP INTERCEPT" mean?

*TCP Intercept* is a firewall function (ASA or IOS) that acts as an inline-proxy for all TCP connections, vs. mere inspection and passing through (with possible NAT rewrite.) This is a means of syn flood protection. "*Valid conns rate*" is the rate of valid (fully completed tcp three-way handshake) connections forming when this feature is enabled.

> why is the average so extraordinarily high?

Bug? I'm assuming you do not have the tcp-intercept feature enabled, so it's using nonsense numbers and/or attempting to divide by zero.

[See Also: [TCP intercept Feature on the ASA device](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/12021641/tcp-intercept-feature-asa-device)]

<sup>(PS: I'm not a fan of Cisco's blog documentation.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a ton, that's definitely what it is. Didn't find even reference to this line of output in any of the ASA CLI guides. One annoyance down!